# create new parent model in CreateView in django

Tags: django

i am new to django and to this site, so apologies if this has been solved before but i haven't found it

So i have 2 django models

```
ModelA(Model):

ModelB(Model):
    modelA = ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A form for the ModelB

```
ModelBForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=ModelB
        exclude=()
```

and a view

```
createModelBView(CreateView):
    model = ModelB
    form_class = ModelBForm
```

the template only does

```
{{form}}
```

When rendered, there is a dropdown list for the ModelA field so I can choose from existing instances of the ModelA, but what if a new one needs to be created? In the admin there is an option next to edit or create a new ModelA in a popup. Is there an option to do this with CreateView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality like that.

However you can build it easily yourself. 
You will have to add a link (or a HTML form) in your template which points to the URL corresponding to the view you implemented to create the given model.

Following is a very abstract example.

In your template:

```
    <form>
      {{csrf_token}}
      {{ form }}
      <a href="/models/createA"> Create model A if you want </a>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <\form>
```

In your urls.py

```
    url(r'^models/createA/$', views.CreateModelAView.as_view(), name="optional")
```

In your views.py

```
    createModelAView(CreateView):
      model = ModelA
      form_class = ModelAForm
```

Then you'll need to create a form called `ModelAForm`.

On a different note, I'd suggest to start off with functional views if you're new to Django. It is more coding but you get a better feel of what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try like that

Answer (score 0):

> In the admin there is an option next to edit or create a new ModelA in a popup. Is there an option to do this with CreateView?

No, not built in. That functionality in the admin involves a lot of front-end work involving templates and routing that would have to come from somewhere; since a Form/ModelForm instance can't assume it has access to the admin (which is a contrib module, may not be enabled, and is permission-sensitive), the infrastructure required for that can't be assumed to be available in the general case.

Keep in mind that `{{ form }}` doesn't even render `<form>` tags or any kind of submit element. It's intended to be a very, very basic way to render a very, very basic set of fields, while the admin is built specifically to be a (reasonably) powerful, flexible way to put a UI in front of your models.

You could certainly build that functionality yourself, or find a reusable app that does the same thing, but there is no facility distributed with Django to generate it automatically.

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed explanation

Comment: @vsnn You're welcome; I hope it helped. I would like to note that, contrary to the suggestion in the other answer, you are on the right track; the newer generic class-based views offer utility and readability advantages for basically anything that's not a simple `render_to_response` function (`TemplateView`).